# Formatting a date and getting its difference compared to today's date and time

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date and time in the format of `2029-11-26T23:59:59`. I want to get its difference compared to today's date and time. The `Date()` function in javascript is a different format in comparison to the date I have. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: You want the difference in what format?  Days? Minutes? Hours? Milliseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference between 2 date/time instances could mean a lot of things - you might want to know the number of seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, months or years between those 2 instances.

You can simply convert your date/time string of the format `2029-11-26T23:59:59` using the `Date()` function, from where you can find out its difference from the current time.

The following function would give you the difference between the 2 times in milliseconds:

```js
function timeDifference(myDateString) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var myDate = new Date(myDateString);
  return myDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime();
}
```

From here, you can convert this difference into any unit - be it minutes, hours, days, months or years. Simply divide the time in milliseconds with the right number. A few examples are shown below:

```js
var myDateString = '2029-11-26T23:59:59';
var oneDayInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var oneYearInMilliseconds = oneDayInMilliseconds * 365;

var differenceInDays = timeDifference(myDateString) / oneDayInMilliseconds;
var differenceInYears = timeDifference(myDateString) / oneYearInMilliseconds;
```

Comment: NB: this assumes myDateString is in local time.

Comment: That's a good point @Jeff. If there's a requirement to deal with different time zones, we can convert the dates into UTC and then do the calculation in the function `timeDifference`.

Comment: Thanks @PranjalNadhani. But how do I convert them to UTC?

Comment: Parsing of strings with the built–in parser is strongly recommended against, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). 2029-11-26T23:59:59 *should* be parsed as local but Safari parses it as UTC. The method used for getting the difference in days is poor, there are [much better answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript).